# web.xml error page definition for different paths

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I know I can specify an error page in web.xml for a certain exception type.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/web_xml.htm#WBAPP537

However, I'd like to specify different error handlers based on the servlet URL patterns. For example, on error normal pages should return an error page, but /ajax URLs should return a different response with an AJAX response indicating the error.
Can I specify a different error page for /ajax URLs from the rest?

Comment: I don;t think you can, but it is simple to put this logic in the error page itself. So the error page is an `if` statement checking the servlet path; if it is /ajax it forwards to the AJAX error servlet/jsp/resource, if not it forwards to the HTML error page.

Comment: Ah, I see I get the path that was being accessed with request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri".